# Mongodb, using aggregate combined with filter?

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to convert a PHP script that is based in a mysql database to run it on a MongoDB database. I have resolved the major queries except one.

Imagine i have a library (this is the collection), every document is a book entry. So I need to know how many distinct authors are in the library wroten in a certain language (another field).

At the moment I have that code and I don't know how to continue:

```
$test = array(
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => array('author' => '$author' )
        )
    )
);
$out = $db->$collection->aggregate($test);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put a filter, you need to start the pipeline with a **$match**,the command will be:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match" : {lang : "en"} },
  {"$group":{"_id": {"author" : "$author"} , "total" : {"$sum" : 1} }} 
])
```

If you convert that to PHP it will be:

```
$test = array(
  array('$match' => array("lang" => "en")),
  array(
    '$group' => array(
        "_id" => array('author' => '$author'),
                    "total" => array('$sum' =>  1)
    ),
  ),
);
```

In this case you have to pass the language in the first step (match/filter).

If you want to could for "all languages" you just need to put the language in the $group operator

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$group":{"_id": {"author" : "$author", lang : "$lang"} , "total" : {"$sum" : 1} }} 
])
```

I let you push this in PHP

You can find more informations about **$match** here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/